# Reprojecting MODIS MCD64A1 to WGS 1984

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, modis

I am part of the technical team of the Autoridad de Fiscalización y Control Social de Bosques y Tierras of the Estado Plurinacional de Bolivia, and we are conducting a multi-temporal study of the dynamics of fires in national territory. It would be very useful to access MCD64A MODIS products ; MCD64A1, we are now mapping products and MCD45A1 MCD45A.

When we try to use the tool "Modis Reprojection Tool" with MCD64A1 , the HDF data files do not have a datum, and that generates a datum error.

Which datum should we use in HDF Products to get geotiff products with projection Geographic datum WGS84?

Answer (score 2):

The products derived from MODIS are generally in Sinusoidal Projection.
In the MODIS Reprojection tool, there is an option to specify its projection to **Geographic**, and then select the **WGS-84 datum**. You can also use MRT in batch mode.